# Adobe Air laggy on Dell Inspiron Touch 1

Tags: air, touch, adobe, touchscreen

OK, this might be a very specific question, but I am seriously stuck.

I have an Adobe Air desktop app which runs fullscreen on a Dell Inspiron Touch PC (OS is Win8). The interaction involves some dragging with the finger/mouse.

**Edit:** I use Air 3.8

Here's my problem: when operated with the mouse, everything works fine and smooth, on this computer and on every other PC I tested it on. But with touch input everything becomes obviously laggy.

When operated by touch, the OS shows a dot which indicates the current position of the recognized finger. When the finger is moved around, this OS output is significantly more responsive than the Air app, where dragging takes longer and lags. So I assume that the problem lies in delivering the touch events to the app.

What I have tried:

- setting different values for MultiTouch.inputMode, assuming that
  MultiTouchInputMode.NONE would be the most performant
- installing a new driver for touch input
- setting the mouse speed of the OS to "high"
- setting the touch area size of the OS to "small"

Nothing did have an impact, and I am out of guesses…

Does someone have an idea or even experience with this stuff?

Thanks!

Comment: Try two things: first, increase `stage.framerate` to 60 just to see if your framerate is not high enough to capture all of the events. Second, throw together a test project that **only** draws a shape on the screen and then moves it to the x,y coordinate of a touch input. Compare the responsiveness of that and the OS indicator, and also try different framerates. The goal is to eliminate either the OS/Device or the App as the issue

Answer (score 0):

Because I had very little time and had to find a solution very quickly (it was a kiosk app for an event), I chose this alternative which worked perfectly: I made a flash file that is shown in the browser in fullscreen. No lag, no performance issues at all. I still don't know what caused this behavior though. No time…